# OpenLayers how to style features when importing from GeoJson file?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson

I'm attempting to style features based on their attributes from a GeoJSON file, however I'm having difficulties

Styling code:

```
        //Style
    var styleFunction = function (feature) {
        var color;        

        if (feature.get("Crime Type") === 'burglary') {
            color = "green";
        } else {
            color = "black";
        }
        var retStyle = new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                image: new ol.style.Circle( /** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */({
                    radius: 5,
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill ({
                    color: color,
                })

                }))
            })
        });
        return retStyle;
    };
```

Adding the markers/features to the map

```
       var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
           source: new ol.source.Vector({
               url: '2017-01-west-yorkshire-street.json',
               format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
           }),

           style: styleFunction
       })
       map.addLayer(vector);
```

However this just renders the map with 0 markers, if I remove the line "style: styleFunction" the map renders with default styling (all blue)

In case you couldn't tell, I'm very new to JS and Openlayers.

Comment: the stroke is not defined properly. The image should not be part of it, and it is missing its components.

Comment: Ok so where would I define the image, and what components is the stroke missing? As far as i know all the others are optional

Comment: For correct definition of styles see this example: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html